# How to compare values from stored in the same table with qlikview?

Tags: mysql, qlikview

being new to qlikview Im a litle confused with I should do in sql and what qlik provides out of the box.

Lets suppose I have a table similar to this :

id  Status  type value quantity dat_s Area
1   Activo  A   10  10  20171001    Norte
2   Activo  B   20  20  20171001    Norte
3   Activo  C   15  15  20171001    Sul
4   Fechado A   5   5   20171101    Norte
5   Activo  B   20  20  20171101    Norte
6   Activo  D   5   5   20171101    Sul
7   Activo  D   5   5   20170901    Sul

Id like to compare a table with itself, but only the likes from selected dates, lets imagine, data A = 20171001 and date B= 20171001 (these should be user defined via an input field or whatever) the comparison id like to do is for example :

Type CountDateA ValDateA CountDateB  ValDateB valuediff
A    1          100          1         25         -75
B    1          400          1         400         0
C    1          225          0         0           -225
D    0           0           1         25          25

or

Area  ValDateA ValDateB valuediff
Norte  500     425      -75
Sul    225     25       -200

I was planing to duplicate the table and use different field names for the same data leaving half empty but I hope there is a more elegant way

Thanks all.

Comment: Could you extend your explanation? it is hard to understand what are you trying to achieve. Where do those 100,400,225 values come from?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the Qlik mechanism. Using only that single  data table entry you can achieve both result tables in the front end. The 2  layers are separate from each other.

Comment: yup, Its my complete inexeprience with qlik, Ive sorted with this kind of expression :   
Count(distinct{<dtimport={$(dtcompA)}>} idtbl_projectos )

Answer (score 0):

just needed to load the table and then the calculations of the clumns would be :

Sum(< Status ={$('Activo')}, dat ={$(20171001)} qty*val)

Answer (score 0):

Still quite confused with your problem. Qlikview's power relies (in few words) on building graphs or tables that are automatically updated depending on selected filters. In your example, I guess, that filter would be the date (or dates) the user selects. Hence, you wouldn't need to define columns like ValDateA, ValDateB etc. In your case however, it seems that you want to compare EXACTLY two dates, so you could define those columns, each of them depending on different date pickers. This being said, I'll show you how I would approach your problem although I'm not really sure whether I understood well:

- I assume you read your data correctly so you have the first data table on memory (with the fields: id Status type value quantity dat_s Area)(note: be careful and consistent with capital letters)
- Create a table chart with dimension "type" (which will autofilter each row expression) and with these expressions:

  1. `Count(distinct{< Status = {"Activo"}, date_s= {"$(vDate1)"}  >} id) //how many rows in active state for date1 (vDate1 is a variable assigned to the first date picker)`
  2. `Sum({< Status = {"Activo"}, date_s= {"$(vDate1)"}  >} value*quantity)`
  3. Same as expression 1 but using `$(vDate2)`
  4. Same as expression 2 but using `$(vDate2)`
  5. In Qlikview you can just write `Column(4) - Column(2)`, in QlikSense you would need to write the whole expressions 2 and 4 again and subtract the sums.